# Squeeze Theorem with strict inequalities

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Suppose that $I$ is an interval, and $g,f,h$ are functions defined on $I$, except possibly at $x_0$. Furthermore, $\forall \varepsilon>0,$ $\forall x\in I,$ and for some constant $L$,
$$ (L-\varepsilon)g(x) < f(x) \le Lh(x) .$$
Also,
$$\lim_{x\to x_0} g(x) = \lim_{x\to x_0} h(x) = 1.$$
Then is it true that $\forall \varepsilon>0,$
$$L-\varepsilon < \lim_{x\to x_0} f(x) \le L,$$
and since $\varepsilon$ can be taken to be arbitrarily small, the middle is forced to give
$$\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)=L?$$
Note that this is essentially the Squeeze Theorem with a strict lower-bound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $L$ is fixed. The quantified statement $$(\forall \epsilon > 0) (\forall x \in I) \quad (L-\epsilon)g(x) < f(x) \le L h(x)$$ implies the quantified statement $$(\forall x \in I) \quad L g(x) \le f(x) \le L h(x).$$ Now apply the squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Generally no: as a rule of thumb, limits only preserve nonstrict inequalities. Thus your second to last line is not always legitimate. In general you get the slightly weaker statement

$$L-\varepsilon \leq \lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) \leq L.$$

One can see this by looking at an example like this: although $1/n>0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $\lim_{n \to \infty} 1/n = 0$.

In this particular case you actually do get the strict inequality, by instantiating the original statement for $\varepsilon/2$, deriving

$$L-\varepsilon/2 \leq \lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) \leq L$$

by the preceding procedure, and then noting that this implies that

$$L-\varepsilon < \lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) \leq L.$$

But working this way really does not do you any good relative to just working with the nonstrict inequality.

Comment: This does not answer the specific question at hand. It is at best a comment.

Comment: @quid I don't see what the problem is. They start from a squeezing inequality where one end is strict, and they take limits on both ends of this squeezing inequality. Then the lower bound becomes nonstrict, which is what I said. I've edited to make the connection to the problem as stated more explicit, but I really don't think that was necessary.

Comment: The problem is that in the described situation it is in fact true that that $\forall \varepsilon>0,$
$$L-\varepsilon < \lim_{x\to x_0} f(x) \le L,$$

Comment: @quid That's true at the end, but it's misleading to write it that way, because you didn't get $L-\varepsilon < \lim_{x \to x_0} f(x)$ by taking limits on both sides of the inequality $(L-\varepsilon)g(x) < f(x)$. Instead you had to use the fact that actually you have the statement with some *smaller* $\varepsilon$ than the one you started with, in order to get the strict inequality for the $\varepsilon$ you started with. It's also unnecessary to write it that way, because the nonstrict inequality is entirely sufficient to prove the result at hand.

Comment: Yes it would be misleading to write it without qualification. But it is **also** misleading to imply it is not true, which is what you did.

Comment: @quid That seems awfully pedantic to me, but I can try to rephrase to accommodate.

Comment: Your original version did not even mention that the final conclusion (the limit is $L$) could still be derived from the non-strict inequality. As such I considered it as highly misleading. I redact the dv on this improved version.

Comment: @quid You mean retract?

Comment: @BCLC what I wanted to say is, I took it back, the dv. Likely retract is the better word to use. But then "redact" does mean remove some statement in a way; but on reflection and checking not really in this context I think. This gives, I am not really sure what I thought about half a year ago when writing that comment, but my best guess is that I just did not pay much attention to the distinction.